# Cmake build from source gives problems on make (probably c++14 standard not used)

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, g++

I just updated my Cmake to the version 3.19 (previously 3.10) from sources. For this I now have two cmake versions the one from before in /usr/bin/cmake and the new one in /usr/local/bin/cmake which does shadow the old one and therfeor seems to be fine.

The problem now I have is that when I compile a c++ program I get problems with missing std:: libraries when I do `make`. I assume this seems to be an issue that g++ is not using c++14 standard and therefore does not see these libraries.

I did not install a new g++ version and the one that I use is GNU 7.5 .0. The old cmake version does work as expected with this.

I installed cmake like this:

```
cd cmake-folder
./configure
make
sudo make install //installs to /usr/local/bin
```

Compiling my programm like this:

```
cd build-folder
cmake ..              //uses new 3.19 version
make                  // gives error of missing std:: libs

cd build-folder
/usr/bin/cmake ..     //uses old defualt 3.10 version
make                  //works
```

Do I somehow have to configure anything special or is my g++ version just not compatible with the cmake version? What else can be the cause?

Comment: What is the error, exactly? Why do you believe that it is because g++ is not using c++14 standard?

Comment: Seems a C++14 compiler is required. ( gcc-6.1 up ) Extra compilers for Ubuntu : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xVEATaYAwqvseBzYxKDzJoZ4-Hc_XOJm?usp=sharing